# How to use parameterized query for Like or Ilike containing multiple single quote string

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I was switching all my queries to parameterized query.But I dont know how I can create a query using parameterized query in LIKE or ILIKE . inputs can be multiple single quote . Like this one ,

`" 'ACCESS_POINT', 'DESKTOP', 'GATEWAY', 'IP_DESK_PHONE', 'IP_TV', 'IP_WEBCAM', 'LAPTOP', 'MAINFRAME', 'MINI_COMPUTER', 'OTHER', 'PRINTER', 'ROUTER', 'SCANNER', 'SERVER', 'SMARTPHONE', 'SWITCH', 'TABLET', 'THERMOSTAT', 'UNKNOWN', 'VM', 'WORKSTATION' "`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do a pattern matching with regular expressions.

You can convert your list into a RegEx - string with an OR - operator between.

- Update thanks to FrankHeikens

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM db.table
WHERE column ~ '(ACCESS_POINT|DESKTOP|GATEWAY|IP_DESK_PHONE|IP_TV|IP_WEBCAM|LAPTOP|MAINFRAME|MINI_COMPUTER|OTHER|PRINTER|ROUTER|SCANNER|SERVER|SMARTPHONE|SWITCH|TABLET|THERMOSTAT|UNKNOWN|VM|WORKSTATION)'
```

Comment: This won't work when using LIKE, you have to use a regex operator, like ~*

Comment: @FrankHeikens you are totally right with the operator

Comment: @dpkandy " 'ACCESS_POINT', 'DESKTOP', 'GATEWAY', 'IP_DESK_PHONE', 'IP_TV', 'IP_WEBCAM', 'LAPTOP', 'MAINFRAME', 'MINI_COMPUTER', 'OTHER', 'PRINTER', 'ROUTER', 'SCANNER', 'SERVER', 'SMARTPHONE', 'SWITCH', 'TABLET', 'THERMOSTAT', 'UNKNOWN', 'VM', 'WORKSTATION' " this one is column value not column it self . and total value is in a string .